# CreateFileAsync() stops debugging and never returned

Tags: c#, .net

Now I'm trying to make UWP application with VS2017 using C#. I use `CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)` to create **two** files at the initial time, to open them afterwards. However **it stopped during opening the second file**(F5, F10, F11 buttons doesn't work during debugging). It runs cool during Creating files or opening the first file. Here is my code.

```
public static StorageFile GetDataFileFromLocalFolder(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName missing");
        }

        return GetDataFileFromLocalFolderAsync(fileName).Result;
    }

    private static async Task<StorageFile> GetDataFileFromLocalFolderAsync(string fileName)
    {
        var sFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var sFile = await sFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        return sFile;
    }
```

Is there any problem? Shouldn't use OpenIfExist option?

Comment: what is the function of `GetDataFileFromLocalFolder` ? Why not use the `GetDataFileFromLocalFolderAsync` function?

Comment: It is probably deadlocking since you are blocking with `.Result`. Ideally every method would be async but you might be able to get away with (a hack) adding `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @Roelant Thanks!! I remove overhead function 'GetDataFileFromLocalFolder'.

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem as avoiding `await` keyword.

```
public static async Task<StorageFile> GetDataFileFromLocalFolderAsync(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName missing"); //remove hard coded string here
        }

        var sFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var sFileTask = sFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        var sFile = sFileTask.AsTask().Result;

        return sFile;
    }
```

Now it works fine. but never knows why....

Comment: Nope, using `.Result` is exactly what causes deadlocks in non-async methods if you're not careful.

Comment: i agree with qbik. Is there a need to step away from your async code? Generally, it is exactly so the main thread won't block :)

Comment: `StorageFile` was opened to read or write just right after the `GetDataFileFromLocalFolderAsync` returns the value. so I wanted this sequence to be sync... but there is no sync method (just `CreateFileAsync` method only in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to create file). @RoelantM